# How to change the resolution and orientation of Windows 10 in Java

Tags: java, windows, javafx, java-8, awt

In Windows 10, it was successful to change the resolution and orientation using DEVMode and user32.dll as cpp code.

But how do I do this in Java code?
JNI? JNA?

My program is in java8, javafx8

Comment: Are you talking about changing the resolution of a full-screen window?  What does it mean to change the orientation?

Comment: @VGR What I want is the resolution and orientation of Windows 10 itself. (windows Settings -> Display Menu)